The vertices of a pentagram are five random points on a circle. Conjecture: The probability that the pentagram contains the circle's centre is $3/8$.
The vertices of a pentagram are five uniformly random points on a circle.

Is the following conjecture true: The probability that the pentagram contains the circle's centre is $\frac38$.

(The pentagram is said to contain the circle's centre if the central pentagon, or any of the five triangles adjecent to the central pentagon, contains the circle's centre.)
A simulation with $10^7$ such random pentagrams yielded a proportion of $0.3750079\approx1.00002\times\frac38$ containing the circle's centre. Thus, my conjecture.

How to set up a simulation
Let the circle be $x^2+y^2=1$ with centre $O\space(0,0)$.
Assume the first random point is $(1,0)$ and let the other four random points be, going anticlockwise from $(1,0)$: $(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)$, $(\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_2)$, $(\cos\theta_3,\sin\theta_3)$, $(\cos\theta_4,\sin\theta_4)$.
Let  $A,B,C,D,E$ be the five regions in the circle and outside the pentagram, going anticlockwise starting with the region between $(1,0)$ and $(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)$.


$O$ lies in $A$ if and only if $\theta_2>\pi,$ and $\theta_4-\theta_1<\pi$.
$O$ lies in $B$ if and only if $\theta_2>\pi,$ and $\theta_3-\theta_1>\pi$.
$O$ lies in $C$ if and only if $\theta_3-\theta_1>\pi$, and $\theta_4-\theta_2>\pi$.
$O$ lies in $D$ if and only if $\theta_3<\pi,$ and $\theta_4-\theta_2>\pi$.
$O$ lies in $E$ if and only if $\theta_3<\pi,$ and $\theta_4-\theta_1<\pi$.

The pentagram contains $O$ just if $O$ lies in none of $A,B,C,D,E$.

If my conjecture is true, then, given the simplicity of the probability, there might be a proof based on some kind of symmetry.

O lies in A if the difference in the blue angles is more than $180^\circ$ and the difference in the red angles is more than $180^\circ$

Something like: Probability in pentagon (not pentagram) is 11/16, and probability in the side triangle (not sector A) is 1/16, so 11/16 - 5*1/16 = 6/16 = 3/8.

@CalvinLin How did you get that the probability in a side triangle is $\frac{1}{16}$ ?

I said "something like", I didn't say I worked out the details of a proof. $\quad$ If you take 2 consecutive points $A, B$, let $A', B'$ be their antipodal points, then $O$  lies in the triangle (framed by $CA, AB, BD$) iff $C, D, E$ lie in arc $A'B'$. Integration should work from here.

Fix some circle (e.g. unit circle as a 1D variety), and a probability measure on it. The probability space we start with is the one of all $P=(P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4)$ tuples of five points on the circle. Denote this configuration space by $C(5)$. Measure on spaces (derived from probability spaces) will always have total mass zero. Let $\Pi=\Pi(P)=\Pi(P_0,P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4)$ be the "solid" area / set of points obtained in the following manner.

Consider one of the points among the five, denote it by $A_0$, then define $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ to be the points so that as sets $\{A_k\ : k\}$ and $\{P_k\ : k\}$ are equal, and so that the $A$-points come in cyclic trigonometric order (anti-clockwise) on the circle.
Let $C_0(5)$ be the space of such $A$-configurations. If i correctly understood which probability should be computed, the event we want to measure is factorizing through this step.
For $A=(A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)$ in $C_0(5)$ let $\Pi(A)$ be the "star" delimited the following five half-spaces:

the half-space delimited by $A_0A_2$ which does not contain $A_1$, but contains $A_3,A_4$
and its "cyclic cousins", determined by $A_{k-1}A_{k+1}$, but not containing $A_k$. (Indices are taken modulo five.)


It may be useful for a bonus to also have a notation for the "inner pentagon", which is the intersection of these half-spaces, we use $\Pi^*(A)$ for it.
Set $\Pi(P)=\Pi(A)$, $\Pi^*(P)=\Pi^*(A)$.
Because of rotational symmetry, we can work in the configuration space of tuples $A$ where $A_0$ is fixed.
We will work now with the circle of length $2$, so that $A_0=0$, and $A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4$ are (identified with) points in this order in the interval $[0,2]$ (instead of $[0,2\pi]$, denote this new configuration space by $\Delta(5)$. (It is a part of a $4$-dimensional simplex.) It will be convenient to write $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ for an element in this space.

We will write below some integrals on configuration spaces, the mass will be omitted, (so we simply write $\int f$ as a "functional in $f$" instead of the measure theoretical notation $\int f\; d\mu$).
The passage from one configuration space to the other is done by the transport formula.
Then we can compute the probability $p$ that $O$ is inside $\Pi(P)$.
The complement, opposite event is the one where $O$ is in one of the regions denote by OP as "region $A,B,C,D,E$". Each such region has the same probability to contain $O$, and exactly one contains it. By rotational symmetry we compute the probability $q$ that $O$ is in the "wrong half-space" w.r.t. both lines $A_0A_2$ and $A_1A_3$, i.e. that the corresponding chords/segments have lengths $\ge 1$. The probability $q$ is thus:
$$
\begin{aligned}
q &
=\int_{C(5)}1_{O\text{ in region $A$ w.r.t. }\Pi(P)}
\\
&=\int_{C_0(5)}1_{O\text{ in region $A$ w.r.t. }\Pi(A)}
\\
&=\int_{\Delta(5)}1_{O\text{ in region $A$ w.r.t. }x}
\\
&=\int_{\Delta(5)}1_{\substack{
0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2\\
x_2-x_0 \ge 1\\
x_3-x_1 \ge 1
}}
\\
&=
\frac
{\operatorname{Volume}
\left(
\begin{split}
x\ :\ 0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2
\\
1\le x_2\\
0\le x_1\le 1\\
1+x_1, x_2\le x_3\le 2\\
x_3\le x_4\le 2
\end{split}
\right)}
{\operatorname{Volume}(x\ :\ 0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2)}
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_0^1dx_1
\int_{\max(1+x_1, x_2)}^2dx_3
\int_{x_3}^2dx_4
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_0^{x_2-1}dx_1
\int_{x_2}^2dx_3
\int_{x_3}^2dx_4
+
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_{x_2-1}^1dx_1
\int_{1+x_1}^2dx_3
\int_{x_3}^2dx_4
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_0^{x_2-1}dx_1
\int_{x_2}^2(2-x_3)\;dx_3
+
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_{x_2-1}^1dx_1
\int_{1+x_1}^2(2-x_3)\;dx_3
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_0^{x_2-1}\frac 12(2-x_2)^2\;dx_1
+
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 dx_2
\int_{x_2-1}^1\frac 12(1-x_1)^2\;dx_1
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 \frac 12(2-x_2)^2(x_2-1)\;dx_2
+
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_1^2 \frac 16(2-x_2)^3\;dx_2
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\left(\frac 1{24}+\frac 1{24}\right)
=
\frac{24}{16}\cdot \frac 2{24}
=\frac 2{16}=\frac 18\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
This leads to the value of the wanted probability $p$:
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
p=1-5q=1-\frac 58=\frac 38\ .\qquad}
$$

Bonus: Let us also compute the probability $p^*$ that $O$
is in the inner pentagon $\Pi^*$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
p^* &
=\int_{C(5)}1_{O\in \Pi(P)}
=\int_{C_0(5)}1_{O\in \Pi(A)}
=\int_{\Delta(5)}1_{\substack{
0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2\\
x_2-x_0 \le 1\\
x_3-x_1 \le 1\\
x_4-x_2 \le 1\\
2 - x_3 \le 1\\
2+x_1-x_4\le 1
}}
\\
&=
\frac
{\operatorname{Volume}\left(
\begin{split}
x\ :\ 0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2
\\
x_2\le 1\\
x_3-x_1 \le 1\\
x_4-x_2 \le 1\\
2 - x_3 \le 1\\
2+x_1-x_4\le 1
\end{split}
\right)}
{\operatorname{Volume}(x\ :\ 0=x_0\le x_1\le x_2\le x_3\le x_4\le 2)}
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_{x_2\in[0,1]}dx_2
\int_{x_1\in[0,x_2]}dx_1
\int_{x_3\in[1,1+x_1]}dx_3
\int_{x_4\in[1+x_1,1+x_2]}dx_4
\\
&=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_{x_2\in[0,1]}dx_2
\int_{x_1\in[0,x_2]}dx_1
\cdot x_1(x_2-x_1)
=
\frac 1{2^4/4!}
\int_{x_2\in[0,1]}\frac 16x2^3\;dx_2
\\
&=\frac 1{2^4/4!}\cdot\frac 1{4!}=\frac 1{2^4}=\frac 1{16}\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Simulation: We let $x$ be a random configuration with five components, one of them equal to zero, in the interval $[0,2]$, and check that no two consecutive cords have length bigger one. The code runs through the sage interpreter.
import random

TRIALS = 10**6
count = 0    # we count successes, so far none 
x0 = 0

for trial in range(TRIALS):
    ok = True
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = [random.uniform(0, 2) for k in [1,2,3,4]]
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = sorted([x1, x2, x3, x4])
    pattern = [x2 - x0 > 1, x3 - x1 > 1, x4 - x2 > 1,
                2 - x3 > 1, 2+x1 - x4 > 1]
    for k in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]:
        if pattern[k] and pattern[(k + 1)%5]:
            ok = False    # and do not count
            break
    if ok:
        count += 1

print(f"Monte-Carlo simulation: p ~ {count} / {TRIALS} = {count/TRIALS.n()}")

(The pattern is something like the sample [False, False, False, True, True], and shows True in the bad case of a chord bigger one. The decision to not count is when two cyclically consecutive True values occur.
And this time i've got:
Monte-Carlo simulation: p ~ 374674 / 1000000 = 0.374674000000000
sage: 3./8.
0.375000000000000

We can modify the do-not-count condition to also simulate $p^*$, by just testing that there is no True entry in the pattern, so ok = True not in pattern, a one liner.
import random

TRIALS = 10**6
count = 0    # we count successes, so far none 
x0 = 0

for trial in range(TRIALS):
    x1, x2, x3, x4 = sorted([random.uniform(0, 2) for k in [1,2,3,4]])
    pattern = [x2 - x0 > 1, x3 - x1 > 1, x4 - x2 > 1,
                2 - x3 > 1, 2+x1 - x4 > 1]
    if True not in pattern:
        count += 1

print(f"Monte-Carlo simulation: p* ~ {count} / {TRIALS} = {count/TRIALS.n()}")

And this time i've got:
Monte-Carlo simulation: p* ~ 62733 / 1000000 = 0.0627330000000000
sage: 1./16
0.0625000000000000

Which supports the computed result in the bonus part...

The moral is that "similar probabilities" (using possibly more points, and special patterns of the position of the center $O$ w.r.t. the sides and diagonals of the cyclically ordered polygon) are volumes of polyhedra (in more dimensions), and can be computed via Fubini as above.

So if we choose five random points on a circle and connect each point to every other point, the resulting $16$ regions all have equal probability of containing the centre of the circle. Amazing!
